# jquery variable in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

On pageload I set a variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inv_count = 3;
  });
```

When I try to refer to that variable inside functions though, it doesn't work.

```
function blah(a,b) {
   alert (inv_count);
   }
```

Why is this? And how can I get around it?

(rookie here)

Comment: make `inv_count` a global variable; it is inside a function. write it outside the `ready` function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you declare a variable inside a function, the variable name will be inaccessible outside the scope of that function. Move the declaration outside the function:

```
var inv_count;
$(document).ready(function() {
    inv_count = 3;
});
```

Comment: because its not a globally accessible variable.

Answer (score 13):

You have a problem of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet), I suggest you read a little about it because you can improve your javascript a ton, but you could solve it in two general ways:

```
var inv_count; //you declare your variable in a global scope, it's not very good practice
$(document).ready(function() {
    inv_count = 3;
});
function blah(a,b) {
   alert (inv_count);
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inv_count = 3;

    function blah(a,b) {
      alert (inv_count);
    }
    //you declare everything inside the scope of jQuery, if you want to acess blah outside use:
   //window.blah = blah;
});
```

Also I recommend you read about [clousures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) if you don't know how they work.